# How to measure time complexity

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity

```py
for i in range(array[0]*2):
     print ("Algorithms are awesome!")

for item in array:
    item *= 1000
    print(item)

for item in array:
    print(item)
```

I want to know time complexity.

Comment: If your code is correct, it would be O(n) for all of them.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is impossible to tell if this is supposed to be three separate loops in series, or a single nested loop, or some other combination.

Comment: This is three separate loops in series in one function.

Comment: In general, algorithmic complexity is computed (as in, maths) not measured (as in, timed).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can take a look at your code and think about how many times a given loop is excecuted. In your case that would be linear (O(n)) for all three loops. Since you only have assignments and print() statements (which can all be done in constant time (O(1))) inside your loops, the total time complexity comes down to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the first one. The number of iterations does not depend on the *size* of the input but on a *numeric value* of input (in your case on the first element of the list).
This means that your algorithm has a [pseudo-polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) time complexity.
So the time complexity is `O(array[0])`. As an example of a pseudo-polynomial algorithm you can consider the dynamic programming algorithm for the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in-advance_algorithm).

```
for i in range(array[0]*2):
     print ("Algorithms are awesome!")
```

For the other two cases, they would both have linear time complexity as you are iterating over the list and both *multiplication* and *print* can be considered basic operations which take constant time.

```
for item in array:
    item *= 1000
    print(item)

for item in array:
    print(item)
```

Comment: If we consider that "numeric value" of the input is a number n, then it's O(n). No need to complicate it.

Comment: It's not a linear time algorithm anymore once your number of iterations depends on the first element of the input. So it's important to distinguish the first case from the others.